# Google Drive API Service Account

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to provide access to folders that have been created using a Rest API call using a Service account (The folders are created and the return values are proper).. but when I try to add a user delegation (using the sub in the JWT header), i keep getting a unauthorized user. I have checked the Service Account creation and everything seems right there. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your request includes the Authorization header with a valid token. Try also to [refresh your access token](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials) using the long-lived refresh token. If this fails, direct the user through the OAuth flow, as described in [Authorizing Your App with Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth).

Check these links:

- [Google drive service account and "Unauthorized client or scope in request"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297710/google-drive-service-account-and-unauthorized-client-or-scope-in-request)
- [Ownership of Google Drive files and Service Account using API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594872/ownership-of-google-drive-files-and-service-account-using-api)